# LogSine Integral $I=-\int_0^{\pi/3} \ln^2\big(2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\big) d\theta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

These are known as LogSine integrals at $2\pi/3$, so I will call the integral Ls as this is common in the literature.  I am trying to prove
$$
Ls=-\int_0^{\pi/3} \ln^2\big(2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\big) d\theta=-\frac{13\pi^3}{162}-2Gl_{2,1}\big(\frac{2\pi}{3}\big)
$$
where $Gl_{2,1}$ can be reduced to one-dimensional polylogarithmic constants.  I know we can write
$$
\ln^2\big(2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\big) =\big(\ln 2+\ln \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\big)^2=\ln^2 2+\ln^2 \cos \frac{\theta}{2} +2\ln 2 \ln \cos \frac{\theta}{2},
$$
but am totally stuck at this point.  Thanks

Comment: What's the closed form?

Comment: @AntonioVargas i have added the closed form for you in the post now.

Comment: @RandomVariable Okay, although I am not sure I see what you're talking about.  Thanks though.

Comment: Nevermind. Your integral involves cosine, not sine. Sorry.

Comment: @RandomVariable Okay, no problem.  Thanks though, as always on your help towards my integrals.  The integral I have just posted has a sine in it (similar to this one, but generalized to nth power), maybe you will know that one.  Thanks.

Comment: In the thread title and your original post you refer to the integral as a log-sine integral even though the integral involves cosine. That's why I was initially confused. Shouldn't it be a log-cosine integral and the notation be (at least according to Borwein) $Lc_{n}(\phi) = - \int_{0}^{\phi} \log^{n-1} |2 \cos \frac{\theta}{2}| d \theta$?  Then this integral would be $Lc_{3}(\frac{\pi}{3})$. I'd edit your post, but I don't like to edit other people's posts except to add tags.

Comment: @RandomVariable No he refers to log cosine as Ls also.  Just see here: http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/logsin.pdf
equation in between (61) and (62).  
However, thanks a lot for your interest on these integrals!  It does make more sense to call it Lc (I agree with you), however this isn't what Borwein does in the paper.

Comment: Notice that on one side he has $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ and on the other side he has $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So he seems to be saying (although I'm not sure at the moment why it is true) that $Ls_{3}(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = Lc_{3}(\frac{\pi}{3})$, not that the integrals with cosine are also called log-sine integrals and referred to using the same notation.

Comment: @RandomVariable I am aware log cosine integrals are not the same as log sine, but he doesn't seem to use this notation anywhere in here, Lc(...).  He just says there are less closed forms known for log cosines and that it can be expressed as this log sine integral. I am not sure either why $Ls(2\pi/3)=Lc(\pi/3)$!  Thanks for catching this mistake, I edited above and put $Ls (2\pi/3)$ instead of $\pi/3$

Comment: All I can find at the moment is a paper in which he refers to log-sine-cosine integrals as $\text{Lsc}_{n}(\phi)$. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4298

Comment: @RandomVariable Excellent find, very helpful for me.  Thanks a lot.   I only have two of his papers, another is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3035v1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the principal brach of $\log z$,
$$\log(1+e^{2ix}) = \log(e^{i x}(e^{-ix}+ e^{i x})) = \log(e^{ix})+ \log(2 \cos x) = ix + \log(2 \cos x) .$$

Squaring both sides,

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /6} \log^{2}(1+e^{2ix}) \ dx = \int_{0}^{\pi /6} \Big( ix + \log(2 \cos x) \Big)^2 \ dx .$$

Then equating the real parts on both sides of the equation and rearranging,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \log^{2} \left( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2}\right) \ dx &= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi /6} \log^{2}(2 \cos x) \ dx \\ &= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi /6} x^{2} \ dx + 2 \ \text{Re} \int_{0}^{\pi /6} \log^{2}(1+e^{2ix}) \ dx \\ &= \frac{\pi^{3}}{324} + 2 \ \text{Re} \int_{0}^{\pi /6} \log^{2}(1+e^{2ix}) \ dx . \end{align}$$

Now make the substitution $z = e^{2ix}$.

Then

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \log^{2} \left( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right) \ dx  = \frac{\pi^{3}}{324} + \text{Re} \frac{1}{i} \int_{C} \frac{\log^{2}(1+z)}{z} \ dz$$

where $C$ is a portion of the unit circle in the first quadrant of the complex plane.

But since we're using the principal branch of $\log z$, $\log(1+z)$ is analytic on the complex plane for $\text{Re}(z) > -1$.

So the path doesn't matter.

And therefore

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /3} \log^{2}\left( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right) \ dx = \frac{\pi^{3}}{324} + \text{Re} \frac{1}{i} \int_{0}^{e^{i \pi/3}} \frac{\log^{2}(1+z)}{z} \ dz .$$

You can find an antiderivative of the integrand in terms of polylogarithms by integrating by parts twice.

$$ \begin{align} \int \frac{\log^{2}(1+z)}{z} \ dz &= \log^{2}(1+z)\log(-z) - 2 \int \frac{\log(1+z) \log(-z)}{z} \ dz \\ &= \log^{2}(1+z) \log(-z) + 2 \text{Li}_{2}(1+z) \log(1+z) - 2 \int \frac{\text{Li}_{2}(1+z)}{1+z} \ dz \\ &= \log^{2}(1+z) \log(-z) + 2 \text{Li}_{2}(1+z) \log(1+z) - 2 \text{Li}_{3}(1+z) + C \end{align} $$

Evaluating the integral at the limits and then simplifying a bit,

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /3} \log^{2}\left( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right) \ dx = \frac{7 \pi^{3}}{324} - \frac{\pi}{6} \log^{2}(3) + \log(3) \text{Im} \  \text{Li}_{2}(1+e^{i \pi /3}) + \frac{\pi}{3} \text{Re} \  \text{Li}_{2}(1+e^{i \pi /3}) $$

$$ - 2 \ \text{Im} \  \text{Li}_{3}(1+e^{i \pi /3}) \approx 0.439089177455491 .$$

Comment: I have a question.  My integral is from 0 to $\pi/3$.  How is yours identical since in your 5th equation, you start with
$$
\int_0^{\pi/6} \ln^2( 2\cos x) dx,
$$
but my integral is 
$$
\int_0^{\pi/3} \ln^2( 2\cos x) dx.
$$
The integrand doesn't seem to have symmetry from 0 to $\pi/6$, so I don't know how they are equivalent.  Thanks.  Or, does everything you did apply to my integral as well, you just solved a different integral?

Comment: It says in the original post that the integral is $\int_{0}^{\pi /3} \ln^{2}(2 \cos \frac{x}{2}) \ dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/6} \ln^{2}(2 \cos x) \ dx$.

Comment: Agh, I see.  I wasn't including the x/2  factor.  Great solution.  I am going through the details, if I have another question, I may ask you.  But for now, thanks again.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation $\text{Gl}_{2,1}$.

Comment: Okay, does this help?  Consider the multiple Clausen functions (Cl) and multiple Glaisher functions (Gl) of depth k and weight w, $w=a_1+...a_k$ defined as 
$$
Cl_{a1,...ak}(\theta)= Im\big(Li_{a1,...ak}(e^{i\theta})\big) \(\text{w even}), \ Re\big(Li_{a1,...ak}(e^{i\theta})\big)\ (\text{w odd}).
$$
$$
Gl_{a1,...ak}(\theta)= Re\big(Li_{a1,...ak}(e^{i\theta})\big)\ \text{(w even)},\ \ Im\big(Li_{a1,...ak}(e^{i\theta})\big)\ \text{(w odd)}.
$$
For our example, $\theta=\pi/3$.  This notation is largely consistent with the mathematical literature.  if you want literature please let me know!

Comment: I evaluated the integral at the limits and simplified a bit.  It might not quite be in the form you seek, but numerically it appears to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, even after I checked it off as the correct answer.  I appreciate it.  I am not doing these integrals for homework, so the form is just fine!  I have recently retired, so I am digging back into all of my mathematics notes and papers and trying to see if I can learn something again!